# how to install locale WITHOUT any additional packages?

Tags: locale

I've installed several locales with
sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack %localename%

Works fine.
But now ubuntu bombarding with notifications about missing language packages  on every startup :(
(for interface maybe? I do not want to change it, why?)
Unfortunately, I can't get rid of ubuntu, because nvidia development tools are all designed for ubuntu 18lts and I need that for my work.

Is there better way to install locations or maybe any way to run nvidia jetpack tools on other linux systems?

Comment: Thee is no such version as Ubuntu 18lts. Do you mean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate (not install) a locale like this:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```

That won't lead to prompts about missing packages.